# How to turn repeating code in to functions when a while loop is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop, dry

I have some extremely repetitive python code that I would like to turn in to a function but I am unsure of the logic as a while loop is involved.

```
#Get initial tracks for playlist and save to JSON file
tracks_file_count = 0
tracks_file_name = f'{str(tracks_file_count)}_tracks.json'
tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'w+')
tracks_response = requests.request('GET', 
  f'{config.global_url}/users/{user}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks',
  headers=headers
)
tracks_file.write(tracks_response.text)
tracks_file.close()
tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'r')
tracks = json.load(tracks_file)
#Save comma seperated track ID's to variable
id_dict = []
for i in tracks['items']:
    track_id = i['track']['id']
    id_dict.append(track_id)
id_comma = (','.join(id_dict))
#Get Audio Features
features_file_count = 0
features_file_name = f'{str(features_file_count)}_features.json'
features_file = open(features_file_name,'w+')
features_response = requests.request('GET', 
  f'{config.global_url}/audio-features/?ids={id_comma}', 
  headers=headers
)
features_file.write(features_response.text)
features_file.close()
features_file = open(features_file_name,'r')
features = json.load(features_file)
track_writer(tracks, playlist_id)
feature_writer(features, playlist_id)
next_url = tracks['next']



while next_url != None:
    tracks_file_count += 1
    tracks_file_name = f'{str(tracks_file_count)}_tracks.json'
    tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'w+')
    tracks_response = requests.request('GET', next_url, 
      headers=headers
    )
    tracks_file.write(tracks_response.text)
    tracks_file.close()
    tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'r')
    tracks = json.load(tracks_file)
    #Save comma seperated track ID's to variable
    id_dict = []
    for i in tracks['items']:
        track_id = i['track']['id']
        id_dict.append(track_id)
    id_comma = (','.join(id_dict))
    #Get Audio Features
    features_file_count += 1
    features_file_name = f'{str(features_file_count)}_features.json'
    features_file = open(features_file_name,'w+')
    features_response = requests.request('GET', 
      f'{config.global_url}/audio-features/?ids={id_comma}',
      headers=headers
    )
    features_file.write(features_response.text)
    features_file.close()
    features_file = open(features_file_name,'r')
    features = json.load(features_file)
    track_writer(tracks, playlist_id)
    feature_writer(features, playlist_id)
    next_url = tracks['next']
```

Link to original [gist](https://gist.github.com/64b2b6d12b/3e7d792a0042755127cfe2eebafefaa5) *(editor's note: indentation not 100% preserved, wrapped lines)*.

In my case, I start of by naming my files with 0_ and then while a condition is not equal to 'None' I do the code again but increment the file name so that it starts with 1_ and so on. The URL also changes. This

[image: diff]

shows that the only changes are incrementing by 1 and the URL.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask], particularly about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Shouldn't `next_url = tracks['next']` be indented so it's inside the loop?

Comment: Why do you think the loop makes it hard to put the code in a function?

Comment: I think the formatting is off, normally it is indented.

Comment: The reason I'm struggling to to turn it in to a function is that there are essentially 2 versions of the almost similar code, the difference between the 2 being the URL being used and the second the incrementing number.

Comment: @Barmar, Dan: Sorry, my fault, I broke the indentation of the last line while copying the wall of code and moving it around... Restored the link to original gist. Is it ok now?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin, it's all good now.

Comment: @Dan Can you make the URL a function parameter? The incrementing number can be a global variable that persists between calls, or you could put the function in a class and make it an object property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the common parts and factor them out into a function:

```
def repetitiveStuff(tracks_file_count, next_url, features_file_count)
  tracks_file_name = f'{str(tracks_file_count)}_tracks.json'
  tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'w+')
  tracks_response = requests.request('GET', next_url, headers=headers)
  tracks_file.write(tracks_response.text)
  tracks_file.close()
  tracks_file = open(tracks_file_name,'r')
  tracks = json.load(tracks_file)
  #Save comma seperated track ID's to variable
  id_dict = []
  for i in tracks['items']:
    track_id = i['track']['id']
    id_dict.append(track_id)
  id_comma = (','.join(id_dict))
  #Get Audio Features
  features_file_name = f'{str(features_file_count)}_features.json'
  features_file = open(features_file_name,'w+')
  features_response = requests.request('GET', 
    f'{config.global_url}/audio-features/?ids={id_comma}', 
    headers=headers
  )
  features_file.write(features_response.text)
  features_file.close()
  features_file = open(features_file_name,'r')
  features = json.load(features_file)
  track_writer(tracks, playlist_id)
  feature_writer(features, playlist_id)
  return tracks['next']


#Get initial tracks for playlist and save to JSON file
next_url = repetitiveStuff(
  0,
  f'{config.global_url}/users/{user}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks',
  0
)

tracks_file_count = 0
features_file_count = 0

while next_url != None:
  tracks_file_count += 1
  features_file_count += 1
  next_url = repetitiveStuff(tracks_file_count, next_url, features_file_count)
```

Note that now the identifiers `tracks_file_count`, `next_url` and `features_file_count` are used *twice*: as arguments to the function, and as global variables / loop variable. The `next_url` is now returned by the  function that creates the `tracks` dictionary.

Comment: I can confirm this worked @Andrey, thank you. I hadn't thought of updating the next_url and at the same time running the function.

Comment: @Dan You're welcome. Yes, indeed, it took a little bit to understand where the `tracks['next']` comes from and where it has to go...